# Can't delete BigQuery dataset that was created via the Python API

Tags: google-bigquery

I can create and delete a BigQuery dataset from the Web UI just fine. But, when I use the Python API to create a dataset, I am not able to delete it. I get an error message that I don't have the "bigquery.datasets.delete" permission for that dataset which is not true because I have the editor role in this project. And, if I can create and delete a dataset from the UI, then I should be able to create and delete a dataset using the API as well, correct?

I don't have any tables in this dataset btw. And, I am using the Python API (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html) to create a dataset by `dataset.create()`

Answer (score 0):

The editor role is not able to delete datasets in BigQuery - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

With that in mind, I'm assuming that you also the project owner, so when you log in to the web UI, you are able to do anything you want. When you are interacting with the Python API, are you using your personal credentials or a service account? If the later, you should ensure that you have given the service account proper access levels to delete.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not the project owner. I just have the Editor role on that project and I can still create and delete a dataset from the Web UI but not using the Python API. I am using my service account credentials with the Python API.

Comment: I just want to be sure that we are talking about the same thing, as the above link I referenced specifically calls out that a data Editor role should not be able to delete datasets. Are you sure that you are not just deleting a table within the dataset?

Comment: Yes, thats right. There is no table in this dataset that I am trying to delete.